# CRS issue converting a GeoTIFF to NetCDF with GDAL

Tags: gdal, netcdf

I'm trying to convert a GeoTIFF with CRS EPSG:2056 to NetCDF. Similar questions suggest to do:

`gdal_translate -of netcdf input.tif output.nc`

Unfortunately this doesn't encode the CRS information in the resulting NetCDF.
By googling I've found and tested also the following:

`gdalbuildvrt output.vrt input.tif`

`gdal_translate -of netcdf output.vrt output.nc`

This returns me the following errors:

`ERROR 1: netcdf error #-50 : NetCDF: Action prohibited on NC_GLOBAL varid .at (e:\buildsystem\src\gdal-3-4-vc15x64\gdal\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,5368)`

`ERROR 1: netcdf error #-50 : NetCDF: Action prohibited on NC_GLOBAL varid . at (e:\buildsystem\src\gdal-3-4-vc15x64\gdal\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,5372)`

I've tried with different GeoTIFFs and with a couple of GDAL version (3.3 and 3.4) on both Linux and Windows.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that EPSG:2056 is not valid in NetCDF but I am not sure because there are several conventions. I checked this one http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.9/cf-conventions.html#appendix-grid-mappings.

I am not sure if this test confirms my assumption or not.

Assign EPSG:2056 and get a failure

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:2056 -of netcdf test.tif output1.nc
Input file size is 2000, 2000
0...10ERROR 1: netcdf error #-50 : NetCDF: Action prohibited on NC_GLOBAL varid .
at (E:\buildsystem\src\gdal-vc17x64\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,5323)

ERROR 1: netcdf error #-50 : NetCDF: Action prohibited on NC_GLOBAL varid .
at (E:\buildsystem\src\gdal-vc17x64\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,5327)
```

Assign UTM Zone 33 and conversion does not give errors

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:32633 -of netcdf test.tif output2.nc
```

I suggest to warp the image into some supported CRS with gdalwarp.

```
gdalwarp -of netcdf -t_srs EPSG:32633 input.tif output.nc
```

Comment: Many thanks for your inputs! I'm not really expert of the NetCDF conventions, anyway I've been able to get a NetCDF file in EPSG:2056 with ArcMap ... but that is ArcMap and I'd prefer using open source tools!